# Name of topology related to cofinite topology

Tags: general-topology

Let $\tau_C$ be the cofinite topology on a set $X$. Let $x\in X$. Does the topology
$$\tau=\tau_C\cup\{\{x\}\}$$
have a special name?

Comment: Well, it's the topology of $Y\coprod\{x\}$, where $Y$ is $X\setminus\{x\}$ with the cofinite topology and $\{x\}$ is the one-point space of $\{x\}$.

Comment: Or the $\{x\}$-extension of the cofinite topology. In general the $A$-extension of a topology $\mathcal{T}$ makes all subsets of $A$ open in the new topology.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think there is a specific name in the literature, but in case you were writing a thesis or some article where this topology appears many times, you may want to define some notation and you may want to call it the *"x-cofinite topology"*.

As Henno Brandsma in noticing in a comment, to be consistent with already existing notation, the "$\{x\}-$*extension of the cofinite topology*" is also working.